# C# filtering a string for specific Regex date and time components

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a `c#` routine that only keeps all date-time information (under some common formatting) that can be found out of any string sentence, by using `Regex`.

Here is what I am trying to do but it does not work...

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{                
    public static string SearchForDateTime(string input)
    {
        // Define common date-time elements.
        string[] SEPARATORS = new string[] { "/", ":" };            
        string[] MONTHS = new string[] { "January", "February", // etc. };
        string[] DAYS = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", // etc. };
        string[] HOURS = new string[] { "AM", "PM", "A.M.", "P.M.", // etc. };

        // Combine pattern elements, adding digitals.
        string separators = String.Join("|", SEPARATORS);
        string months = String.Join("|", MONTHS);
        string days = String.Join("|", DAYS);
        string hours = String.Join("|", HOURS);
        string pattern = $"{separators}|{months}|{days}|{hours}|[0-9]";

        // Replace anything that is not a date-time element by an empty string. 
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, $"[^{pattern}]", "");

        return output;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input1 = "Hello John, today is 25 January 2024 10:15 AM in Miami";
        string input2 = "Hello Jane, today is 25/01/2024 10:15P.M. in Boston";

        Console.Write("Input 1: " + input1);      
        Console.Write("Output 1: " + SearchForDateTime(input1));             
        Console.Write("Input 2: " + input2);
        Console.Write("Output 2: " + SearchForDateTime(input2)); 
    }
}
```

Now if I run this code for the input string: "Hello John, today is 25 January 2024 10:15 AM in Miami" or "Hello Jane, today is 25/01/2024 10:15P.M. in Boston", the returned string output is unchanged... Any idea?

---

### ADDENDUM

Maybe, let's rephrase with something simpler to start with. Say, I would like to keep any whole month name that is within the vector of month names that can be found out within any string sentence and eliminate the rest.

```
    public static string SearchForDateTime(string input)
    {
        // Define common month elements.
        string[] MONTHS = new string[] { "January", "February", // etc. };

        // Combine pattern elements, adding digitals.
        string months = String.Join("|", MONTHS);
        string pattern = $"{months}";

        // Replace anything that is not a month element by an empty string. 
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, $"[^{pattern}]", "");

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: You will always need a more specific regex to detect more specific date/time patterns. "Just any" won't fly because that's going to be ambiguous.

Comment: To investigate your regex, though, I'd recommend to use a website like regex101 where you can test your regex against sample input. It also breaks down your regex and makes it easy to spot misconceptions in the syntax.

Comment: This job is impossible for regex, you need [tag:LLM].

Comment: You need one regex for one date and time format. And run all on input string.

Comment: The regex `[^monday|tuesday|wednesday]` is equivalent to `[^mondaytuesw|]` which is a equivalent to `[^ademnostuwy|]`. The `[^...]` is a negated character class, not a general negation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: ^^ And even that might fail. There could be instances where you'll even need to consider a wider context.

Comment: This is not a solved problem. It is **NOT POSSIBLE** to parse any random date from unstructured input, because certain date formats in common use are **ambiguous** and **conflicting**, resulting in _multiple possible valid interpretations for the same input_ for a large swath of possible inputs. While humans can _usually_ (not always!) do this from context clues, a computer often does not have or cannot use or understand the appropriate context.

Comment: @Fildor. Thank you for the tip re. regex101. I have started to play with the tool but I am still not finding an answer to my negate regex question...

Comment: You might try the `Regex.Split` method (or one of its overloads). Wrap the text of the regex in capturing brackets. Then remove the unwanted items from the array. Search the [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-8.0) page for the example with `Regex regex = new Regex("(-)");`.

Comment: For example, if I build a pattern =(January|February|[0-9]|AM|PM|:|\/) and apply it to the string "Hello John, best months are January and February, best days are 1/01/2024 and 29/02/2024, best times are 10:15AM and 10:30PM.", I get a regex selection "Hello John, best months are  and , best days are  and , best times are  and .". What I would like to achieve, is the mirror of this...

Comment: Your desire is clear, but regexs do not easily do that. Regexes can solve many problems but they are not a panacea.

Comment: Also take into account that something may _look_ like a date but actually not be one. For example: I had to deal with document recognition and data extraction. There, one of the clients had material identifiers that had the form `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}-[acnr]{3}\d{7}` (wow still from the top of my head ...) which lead to constant false positives and needed to be thrown out by position / context.

Comment: @Fildor and @AdrianHHH. Thank you for your help. I did what you suggested, namely, started with a `Regex.Split` before eliminating what I did not want to keep. I end up with something that seems to work decently. It will probably require some further tuning, as new cases of my problem of "commented and sentenced dates and times" arise. Thanks again for directing me to the regex101 website that is indeed very useful.